# how to delete temp and log files with terminal on vps?

Tags: debian, logs, tmp

Anyone know how to delete any temp and log files or these kind of files on vps with terminal? I'm runnin debian on the vps. I can't locate those files.

Comment: What kind of temp and log files are you worried about? Is it e.g. your browser's cache, or files created by other programs you run?

Answer (score 2):

On a debian based machine temporary and log files are probably in

```
/var/tmp
/tmp
/var/log
```

or some subdirectory of those paths. However there is no guarantee that a program writes them there. To remove them you probably need `root` privileges and use `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Type this step by step:

```
cd /
rm -rfv tmp
mkdir tmp
cd var
rm -rfv log
mkdir log
rm -rfv tmp
mkdir tmp
```

Note:

- cd is locate to directory; / is root
- rm is remove; -rf for remove folder; -v is for view process; -rfv is combined of -rf and -v
- mkdir is create folder

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try Blechbit application its a package manager from synaptic, download it then follow the below tips....

open terminal>> Login by su and password..

type bleachbit as it will be launched as a root login .Now you can select all ‘cache’ from all your browsers and other non-essential files or anu log you want to delete and hit ‘delete’ it ll remove the log...

Or 
Find the log file whr its been generated,
then rm -rf logs file... thats it..
You can find the log file location in the conf file of your application..

Comment: thanks for the info! since i'm using putty to connect I must type the command to delete them

Answer (score -2):

then you can try 2nd option..
can find the log file and rm -rf the log file..

rm -rf = delete 
rm = Remove specified files or directories.
-rf is the option but use this command carefully as it is very powerfull command if u delete any system file, Your system may stuck..

Comment: **DO NOT** recommend using `rm -rf` without knowing what it does and what the arguments mean!